# Entity Framework Migrations Error using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting an error running Entity Framework migrations after updating to Visual Studio 2013.

```
    PM> update-database
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetTargetDir(Project project)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

Anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: One important note is that I don't have any other version of Visual Studio installed as this is a new computer.  Looks like this assembly came with Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to fix this using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package.  After I installed the package update-database worked correctly.

```
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending code-based migrations.
Running Seed method.
```

Comment: With a fresh installation of Visual Studio Express (2013) for Web, new Internet Application Project, etc, I was still having problems even after installing the redistributable packages for either VS 2012 Shell or 2013 Shell (Isolated). DLL exists, but it still didn't pick it up for one reason or another. `Enable-Migrations` did actually work if I went back to using Visual Studio 2012 though. Maybe it's broken in 2013 these days...

Answer (score 1):

Update from EF 5 to EF >6, it works!

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in EF 5 that is corrected in EF 6.

More details can be found [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/805933/filenotfoundexception-enabling-ef-migration) and [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1658).

Comment: I was using EF6 when I received this error. EF6 was installed using this command.  Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.1

Comment: Only VS2013 is installed on my laptop (Windows 8.1) and EF6 works well where EF5 is complaining about "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell" assembly. Maybe a slightly different issue.

Comment: Yes must be.  I was also running Windows 7 not 8.1.